# JavaScript - Reverse of Math.cos(30)

Tags: javascript, math

`Math.acos(Math.cos(30))` will not return 30, but `Math.acos(Math.cos(0.7))` will return 0.7... How can I do it correctly?

Comment: The Math.cos() method returns a numeric value between -1 and 1, which represents the cosine of the angle.

Comment: I know, but how can I get 30 from Math.cos(30)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because the input/parameter to the `cos` function should be in **radians** not in degrees.

From MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos):

> Parameters
>
> x : A number given in unit of **radians**.

So, before making call to the function, convert the input to radians.

Make use of formula `Radians = Degrees * ( Pi / 180)`

Comment: `radians = 30 * ( Math.PI / 180); Math.acos(Math.cos(radians))` will not return 30, because it can only return a number from -1 to 1. How can I get 30?

Comment: Hmmm, take time to check the docs, friend. Even the return value will be in radians. *The Math.acos() method returns a numeric value between 0 and π radians for x between -1 and 1*. So convert it back to degrees.

Comment: I just converted `Math.acos(...)` to degrees: `radians * (180 / Math.PI)` and it returned 30. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Convert 30 degrees to radians

```
var radians = 30 * Math.PI / 180;
document.write(radians);
var result = Math.cos(radians);
var andBackToRadians = Math.acos(result);

document.write('<p>'+result+'</p>');
document.write('<p>' + andBackToRadians + '</p>');
```